# Show Uniqueness of Solution for Boundary Value Problem

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $G \subseteq R^n$ be a simple, connected and bounded region with smooth boundary and let $f : \overline G \to \mathbb R$, $g : \partial G \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Show that the following boundary value problem $\Delta u = f$ and
$$
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + \alpha u \Big|_{\partial G} = g, \quad \alpha > 0
$$
has at most one solution.

Any hints how to show this, most of the time I can show uniqueness by applying the maximum principle, but here I do not see how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there are two solutions, $u_1,u_2$, satisfying the bvp. Let $w=u_1-u_2$, then $w$ satisfies $$\Delta w=0$$ on $G$, and $$\partial w/\partial n+\alpha w|_{\partial G}=0$$ now multiply by  $w$ and integrate by parts: $$0=\int_G w\Delta w dx =\int_G\nabla\cdot(w\nabla w)-\nabla w\cdot \nabla w dx=\int_{\partial G}w\nabla w\cdot n dS-\int_G\nabla w\cdot \nabla wdx$$

$$=-(\int_{\partial G}\alpha w^2 dS+\int_G\nabla w\cdot \nabla wdx)$$

thus $\nabla w=0$ in $G\Rightarrow w=C$ in $G$.

but also we have $w=0$ on $\partial G$, so by the continuity of $w$, we have $$0=w=u_1-u_2$$

Thus $u_1=u_2$.

Comment: It is noteworthy that $\partial w/\partial n=\nabla w\cdot n$

Comment: Why does $$0 = -\int_{\partial G} \alpha w^2 dS + \int_G \nabla w \cdot \nabla w dx$$ implies $\nabla w = 0$ in $G$, the boundary term could compensate any positive value of the integral over $G$. And why we have $w = 0$ on $\partial G$?

Comment: The whole thing is positive, there should be no minus sign, since,on $\partial G$, $\nabla w\cdot n=-\alpha w$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $g=0$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
   0=\int_{\Omega} u\nabla^{2}u\,dV 
      & = \int_{\Omega}(\nabla\cdot(u\nabla u)-|\nabla u|^{2})dV \\
      & = \int_{\partial\Omega}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\,dS-\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}\,dV \\
      & = -\alpha\int_{\partial\Omega}u^{2}dS-\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}\,dV.
\end{align}
$$
NOTE: The reason I assumed $g=0$ was because the difference of two solutions will be a solution of your problem with $g=0$, and that's what you want to show is $0$.

Comment: Why would you assume that $g=0$?

Comment: I edited the post to explain.

Comment: These are things that you should have really explained, as in this context the maths is wrong, even though the calculus is right, the set up is important.

Comment: @ellya , I was giving an outline. The person has likely been dealing with uniqueness proofs lately, and they probably don't need much to get unstuck. The big idea is usually all that's needed to get someone going. That's my Philosophy in teaching; you're welcome to your own. Did you read that he asked for "any hints..."